# Are there no solutions to this linear congruence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve the following linear congruence:

Solve the congruence $7x \equiv −13 \,\,\text{mod}\,\, 11$

Are there actually any solutions to this? Doesn't seem so since the possibilities for any number mod 11 is 0 to 10, it's impossible for x mod 11 to be negative, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there actually any solutions to this? Doesn't seem so since the possibilities for any number mod 11 is 0 to 10, it's impossible for x mod 11 to be negative, right?

Perhaps you think that "$-$" in "$-13\text { mod }11$" applies to the whole expression, i.e. "$-(13\text{ mod }11)$" while in fact it should be understood as "$(-13)\text{ mod }11$".

You are right that $x\text{ mod }n$ is a number between $0$ and $n-1$. This doesn't however mean that $x$ cannot be negative. In fact $x\text{ mod }n$ is well defined for negative $x$ via this simple rule:

$$-1\equiv n-1\text{ mod }n$$

By this rule if $x<0$ then $-x>0$ and thus

$$x\equiv (-1)\cdot (-x)\equiv (n-1)\cdot (-x)\text{ mod }n$$

which turns negative congruence into a positive one.

So in your case $x=-13$ and $n=11$. Therefore

$$-13\equiv 10\cdot 13\equiv 130\equiv 9\text{ mod }11$$

And so our equation can be written as

$$7x\equiv 9\text{ mod }11$$

Now $7$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ and its inverse is $8$. Thus multiplying both sides by $8$ we get the solution

$$x\equiv 6\text{ mod } 11$$

Comment: It's not uncommon to use "mod $n$" as an operator that reduces numbers to the range $0, \ldots, n - 1$ but I think this is misleading.  It makes students think that, for example, $3 = 8$ mod $5$ is true but $8 = 3$ mod $5$ is false.  It's better to think of "mod $n$" as a modifier that changes what the equals sign means, it applies to the *entire equation*.  With that in mind I would not say that $x$ mod $n$ is a number between $0$ and $n - 1$.  That's true for mod as an operator, but that's not how mod is being used when students solve modular equations.